# Unable to generate public key from given mod and exp. Throws "Bad Data"

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I wanted to know and understand the process to generate the JWE. I have given below details:

`string mod = "2737";` // this is a 618 char long string constructed only with digits.

`string exp = "65537";`

`string kid = "APIKEY.XX.665_Priv";`

`string keyEncAlgo = "RSA-OAEP";`

`string contentEncAlgo = "A256GCM";`

And a `payload` in `json` format.

As with my limited knowledge in this field I proceeded with creating a public key using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. And planned to use `Jose.Jwt` library.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAPaeameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAPaeameters();
rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = Encode.ASCII.GetBytes(mod);
rsaKeyInfo.Exponent = Encode.ASCII.GetBytes(exp);
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);
```

The last line in the above code `rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo)` throws exception as `bad data`.

Although the same `mod` and `exp` being used in a Java app which eventually gets everything right. I am converting that Java code to C#. What I am doing here wrong. Or I have understood the process wrong.

Comment: It's unlikely that those `mod` and `exp` are ASCII strings.

Comment: @jps Updated the question

Comment: @Evk What are the possibilities if not ASCII.

Comment: Plenty of possibilities. Could be hex, base64, or even just plain number, because both modulus and exponent are actually just numbers (exponent is very big number). ASCII is quite unlikely because none of those values are text, so why would someone use text encoding for that? But anyway that's you who must know what these values are and in what encoding, if any, because you got them somewhere after all.

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or Core and which version?

Comment: @Topaco its .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @Evk Figured that it is just a very long decimal number (in string format). thanks for the direction. `BigInteger` did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulus (assuming that 2737 is merely the beginning) and exponent appear to be decimal representations (as string).

Under .NET5+ (and .NET Core 2.1+) these can be imported as follows:

```cs
using System.Numerics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
string mod = "2737...";
string exp = "65537";
var rsaPublic = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaPublic.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters
{
    Modulus = BigInteger.Parse(mod).ToByteArray(true, true),
    Exponent = BigInteger.Parse(exp).ToByteArray(true, true)
});
```

Note that the byte arrays are unsigned (1st `true`) and with big endian byte order (2nd `true`).

---

An example of JWE with [jose-jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jose-jwt/) is:

```cs
using Jose;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
IDictionary<string, object> addHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "kid", "APIKEY.XX.665_Priv" },
};

string payload = "some string";
string token = JWT.Encode(payload, rsaPublic, JweAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, JweEncryption.A256GCM, null, addHeaders);
```

with the following header (if Base64 decoded):

```js
{
    "alg":"RSA-OAEP",
    "enc":"A256GCM",
    "kid":"APIKEY.XX.665_Priv"
}
```